# disable command prompt c# empty project

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I'm making a simple text-editor form program using Visual studio.
I've used the project type "empty",
When the program is run, the command prompt appears along with the form object.

How could I stop this system32\cmd.exe shell from starting?
Thanks.

Comment: Use a Windows Forms (or WPF) project instead of a Console Application.

Comment: a) It's not a cmd shell, it's conhost.exe. b). As noted, use WPF or WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When choosing a type of project you shouldn't have used Console application, but appropriate type depending on GUI technology you want to use.

You can do following, depending on version of Visual Studio (I don't have it opened at moment):

1) go to Project Settings -> General Settings
2) change Application type to Windows Application

Comment: I could not find  "Project Setting" on VS 2013 (same year as answered). I think you can go to Project Properties and change Output type to "Windows Application" but I just went with WPF as mentioned by kanr.